# Django nginx config is blocking admin

Tags: django, nginx

So I am trying to block bots and other bad things from my website so I added this inside my `nginx.conf` file but I realized that it blocks my `www.example.com/admin` and returns it to 404.

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ (libwww|Wget|LWP|damnBot|BBBike|java|spider|crawl) ) {
            return 403;
    }
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Hospii_Landing_page/Hospii_Landing.sock;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is caused by the user agent check as you're returning a 403 not 404. I think you should search for a good nginx example with a django app.

Comment: Do you have `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),` in your main `urls.py`?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir yes I do have it

Comment: @Mounir yes it is caused by that because if I comment that it works again